# AJAX HTTP error occurred while updgrading Drupal to version 7

Tags: ajax, upgrading

I upgrade my Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.
At the last step, I opy all the Drupal 7 files into my main directory. 
While I run update.php, at the run update step.
The following error appear.

> An unrecoverable error has occurred. You can find the error message
>   below. It is advised to copy it to the clipboard for reference. Please
>   continue to the error page
>
> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   http:// site.com/update.php?op=selection&token=y5Ljf9tW9wL5n0yanpS-ezpQTQb5JJ1wZhLfqRnjShs&id=34&op=do
>   StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText:

[image]

Comment: First thing check your php and Apache error logs.

Comment: HTTP 500 means "check server logs", so pleas do, and share what you find.